# Django forces primary key on field named `id` even if another field is already declared primary key

Tags: python, django

These are my requirements, and I can not change them:

- I have a field named `name`. That is my primary key
- I have a field named `id`, but it is not my primary key.
- The `id` is also an auto-increment field.

I have several problems:

1. Auto-increment fields must be primary keys in django
2. Django sets `primary_key` in fields called `id`:

I have been able to work around the first problem, by using this:

```
from django.db.models.fields import AutoField
from django.db.models.fields import checks


class AutoFieldNonPrimary(AutoField):

    def _check_primary_key(self):
        if self.primary_key:
            return [
                checks.Error(
                    "AutoFieldNonPrimary must not set primary_key=True.",
                    obj=self,
                    id="fields.E100",
                )
            ]
        else:
            return []
```

Now I can do:

```
class TheNiceUser(models.Model):
    id = AutoFieldNonPrimary()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=16, primary_key=True)
```

But still, the id is declared as primary key. Now I have two primary keys in my model, and the migrations complain.

According to the [django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields), this should not be the case: if a field has `primary_key` set, django should not add an `id` field as primary key.

But what happens if I declare an `id` field? It seems that django insists on making that a primary key, even if another field is already declared as primary key.

How can I get out of this situation?

Comment: why do you add the field id? Django automatically has a field id for all the models, it just says in the docs declare the primary_key=True on a field that's all

Comment: @SammyJ, requirements. But to clarify: I need an auto-increment field, called id. There are other tools interacting with this database, and they expect to find that field.

Comment: But why don't you want the ID to be the primary key? And why do you want the name to be the pk?

Comment: The point is of course that AutoField automatically defines `primary_key=True` and you haven't overridden that anywhere. You could do that, but your requirements are odd.